# Is there any way to convert File object to DataInputStream Object in Java?

Tags: java, file

I have a object of File and I want to convert it into a **DataInputStream** Object.
is there any way to do it?

I have these objects.

```
        FileOutputStream fos;
        File outputFile;
        outputFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".xlsx");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

after that i am writing the data into file

```
excel.write(fos);
fos.close();
```

Now, I want to convert the file into the DataInputStream object.
How can I do it?

Comment: Output streams allow you to write data, input streams allow you to read it. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: There is [**piped I/O**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) in java, using two threads, one to write, one to read. It origin in the Unix `|`, like `listallfiles | find 'wonder'`. An intermediate file does seem to be needed.

Comment: @tgdavies actually i don't want to use file directory. so i have file object already present with data. I intend to use an inbuilt function which takes DataInputStream as an input. so i am just wondering how to do conversion

Comment: DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

Comment: You can convert file to DataInputStream. Input streams work for reading.